# ERRO AO INICIAR .EXE PYTHON

Tags: python, chatbot, .exe, chatterbot, pyinstaller

Olá, eu estou criando um chatbot em Python usando a biblioteca Chatterbot, então eu tentei transformar o meu simples código Python em um arquivo .exe para que outras pessoas possam testar, eu estou usando o pyinstaller.

Eu instalei ele pelo prompt de comando: `pip install pyinstaller` depois eu entro na pasta que está o meu código pelo cmd, e digito: pyinstaller [nome_do_arquivo.py], e ele roda tudo certinho, faz a compilação de todos os arquivos, mas o problema está quando eu executo o arquivo .exe, que ele mostra esse erro. E eu gostaria de ajuda pra resolver isso. [image: Como este]

Esse é o meu código

```py
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot import ChatBot

bot = ChatBot('Aiby')
bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)

Train = ['Oi', 'Olá','Como vai?', 'Vou bem e você?', 'Vou bem também!']

bot.train(Train)


while True:
    ask = input('Você: ')                       
    answer = bot.get_response(ask)
    if float(answer.confidence) > 0.0:
        print('Aiby: ', answer)
    else:
                print("Aiby: Acho que não sei como responder a isso, me desculpe!")
```

Se precisar de mais detalhes pode comentar aqui embaixo, estarei disposto a ajudar você a me ajudar!!!
Já agradeço antecipadamente!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo você pode tentar antes de você criar o programa, crie uma pasta chamada "Lib" na pasta raiz do seu projeto e arraste as bibliotecas que seu programa usa lá pra dentro. as bibliotecas no windows ficam no diretório a seguir

"H:\Users\seu usuário\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages

no "H" o seu pode ser diferente, ai tu pode trocar para a letra da sua partição e no usuário tu coloca o nome do seu usuário.